# Resize for GridViewColumn is doing bizarre things

Tags: c#, wpf, listview

I am experiencing some bizarre behavior when attempting to resize columns across data templates.

Background:

I have an outer `ListView` which is bound to a set of categories. I then have an inner `ListView` where I have a `GridView` as its view.
Now I have bound the `GridViewColumn` width to `GridViewColumnHeader` so that the `GridViewColumns` are adjusted accordingly.

Sample code:

```xml
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Categories, Mode=TwoWay}">
  <ListView.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
      <Expander Header="{Binding Description}">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
          <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
              <!-- Description column -->
              <GridViewColumn Width="{Binding ElementName=DescriptionCol, Path=Width}">
                <GridViewColumn.Header>
                  <GridViewColumnHeader Name="DescriptionCol" Content="Description" 
                                        SizeChanged="Description_Column_SizeChanged" 
                                        HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
                                        Loaded="Description_Column_Loaded">
                  </GridViewColumnHeader>
                </GridViewColumn.Header>
                <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                  <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Name="DescriptionTextBlock" Text="{Binding Description}" 
                               Style="{StaticResource TextBlock_GridEntries_Style}"
                               Margin="{Binding HierarchyLevel, Mode=OneWay, Converter={StaticResource HierarchyToMarginConverter}}"/>
                  </DataTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
              </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
      </Expander>
    </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Now I am attempting to bind column widths across Categories by capturing the `GridViewColumnHeaders` objects and storing them in a special `GridViewColumnCommunal` object.

```
private GridViewColumnCommunal descriptionColumns = new GridViewColumnCommunal();

private void Description_Column_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var gridViewColHeader = sender as GridViewColumnHeader;
    if (descriptionColumns != null)
    {
        descriptionColumns.AddColumnToListAndResize(gridViewColHeader);
    }
}
```

Where the `GridViewColumnCommunal` class is :

```
public class GridViewColumnCommunal
{
    private List<GridViewColumnHeader> _columns = new List<GridViewColumnHeader>();

    public List<GridViewColumnHeader> Columns
    {
        get { return _columns; }
        set { _columns = value; }
    }

    public void UpdateColumnsItemsWithLargestColumnWidth()
    {
        if (Columns != null)
        {
            var maxWidth = Columns.Max(x => x.ActualWidth);
            foreach (var column in Columns)
            {
                column.Width = maxWidth;
            }
        }
    }

    public void AddColumnToListAndResize(GridViewColumnHeader columnToAdd)
    {
        if (columnToAdd != null && Columns != null && !Columns.Contains(columnToAdd))
        {
            Columns.Add(columnToAdd);
            UpdateColumnsItemsWithLargestColumnWidth();
        }
    }

    public void UpdateColumnsWithNewWidth(Size size)
    {
        if (Columns != null)
        {
            foreach (var column in Columns)
            {
                column.Width = size.Width;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Now when I attempt to resize a column by any small amount, it gets resized by a significant amount. As a sample:

**Before:**
[image: Before image]

**After:**
[image: Afterimage]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try change your method `UpdateColumnsItemsWithLargestColumnWidth` like below:

```
public void UpdateColumnsItemsWithLargestColumnWidth()
    {
        if (Columns != null)
        {
            var maxColumn =Columns.First(y=>y.Column.ActualWidth == Columns.Max(x => x.Column.ActualWidth));
            foreach (var column in Columns)
            {                    
                column.Column.Width = maxColumn.Column.ActualWidth;
            }
        }
    }
```

As you want to resize the `Column` `Width`. If you'll set only the `Width` of `GridViewColumnHeader` it may not force the whole column `Width`. But if you set the `Column` `Width` it will also resize the `GridViewColumnHeader` `Width`.

Comment: You are an absolute legend. This has resolved the issue!